# Apache passenger configuration for my rails3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I have followed these steps to configure passenger (3.0.11) on latest apache httpd server.

```
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I have a virtual host configuration which points to my rails3 app internally and I have started the apache http server. I am able to access the app with the port configured in httpd.conf. The /etc/init.d/httpd script is used to start/stop the apache httpd server. Do I need to start the passenger server separately or the existing configuration is fine (I am assuming since that we are using the passenger plugin for apache, we don't need to start the passenger server)

Answer (score 0):

Passenger is a module for Apache. As long as you have followed the instructions and included Passenger in the Apache configs it will be started/stopped as a part of apache.